# Is this a correct usage of "is to"?

Tags: verbs

Does this phrase use the `is to` form correctly?

> Another thing that company could do **is to** provide free coffee at work.

Comment: This *is to* comment that yeah, it's fine! :)

Comment: Provide some context?

Comment: @Adam "Another thing that company could do is to provide free coffee at work."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Another thing that company could do is to provide free coffee at work.

is a valid use of `is to` as it indicates future obligation [by the company]. It is akin to making a suggestion/recommendation, like:

> The company should also provide free coffee at work.

Comment: It isn't necessarily a suggestion or recommendation, it is just an option. *Could* and *should* don't mean the same thing.